# Can't open JS File in Chrome Dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

i have a poor understanding of js and webpack.

I want to know which js file is triggerd when i press a button. From the chrome dev tools -> Event Listener -> Click -> There i get a few js filenames. But When i click on it, i get the following message:

```
Inhalt für webpack:///node_modules/@sentry/browser/esm/helpers.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP-Fehler: Statuscode 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME) konnte nicht geladen werden
```

Translated to english...

```
Content for webpack:///node_modules/@sentry/browser/esm/helpers.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME) could not be loaded
```

Also in the debug mode i can't see the js file.

What can i do to see the js file?